# GTest Floats less or close with absolute error

Tags: c++, unit-testing, floating-point, googletest

The assertion macros of googletest are pretty great because they provide with nice messages in case of failure. I am looking for a nice possibility for a more complicated float comparison:
"Less than or close with given accuracy for the latter"
So according to the [Advanced Guide on github](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md) this is at least possible without giving a maximum absolute error for how close the floats may be:

```
EXPECT_PRED_FORMAT2(::testing::FloatLE, val1, val2);
```

Just right above they say how "close with given error" works:

```
EXPECT_NEAR(val1, val2, abs_error);
```

So I thought a combination must work, too. Looking at the source code, how the EXPECT_NEAR expands I see that there are higher order macros like

```
EXPECT_PRED_FORMAT3
```

which accept again another value. However, I could not get this combination to work in a straight forward way.

So the question is: Is this possible at all and how?

Of course one can do a workaround, coding the comparison and just comparing a boolean. However, this lacks the nice gtest output in case of failure.

Comment: why not just use two expectations to the same numbers just one after another, in simple sequence?

Comment: If you do that you ensure that one of them is always false and the test fails - this renders it useless. Imho there is no possibility to say "Either this or that" with gtest in general. If I am wrong I would be happy to learn about that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXPECT_PRED3(pred, val1, val2, val3)` but you will have to write your own *pred* function, which takes 3 arguments and returns `true` or `false`.

If you want nice messages, you should write your own function that takes 3 arguments and returns `::testing::AssertionResult`, as described in the Google Test documentation, [Using a Function That Returns an AssertionResult](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#using-a-function-that-returns-an-assertionresult). You can then use that function with `EXPECT_TRUE`.

Comment: So I wrote a function
AssertionResult FloatSmallerOrNear(float a, float b, float absErr)
which works with an EXPECT_TRUE. But I thought the following should also be possible then, however it does not compile (too many arguments, expected 3):
EXPECT_PRED_FORMAT3(FloatSmallerOrNear, a, b, 0.1)
Do you understand why? Apparently I misunderstand the docu in this point.

Comment: You should use `EXPECT_PRED3` not `EXPECT_PRED_FORMAT3`. Also when you use `EXPECT_PRED3` your _pred_ function should return a boolean, not AssertionResult.

Comment: Shame on me, I confused that. Thanks a lot! Still wonder why it said it with _FORMAT on the github page, but that should be it. I'll try that right away!

Comment: Works! Thank you very much!